# Check JavaScript before submitting / Deny access to global variables

Tags: javascript, validation

I have made a math formula editor which allows the user to enter a math formula. This will then be converted to a JavaScript equation in a string, which will be executed using `eval()`. The user will also be able to submit it so that other users can view his function. The big problem with this is that it would be possible to enter JavaScript code in the formula, which would then be executed by the browsers of other users viewing it. I unfortunately can't just escape the formula because I am converting things like Sinus to a `Math.sin()` function. I am open to any suggestions how I can prevent the user from putting JavaScript code into the Math formula, here are my ideas:

1. Somehow check the code. The problem is that as said I can't just scan for any JavaScript function because I am using things like `Math.sin()` or `Math.log()`. So I would like to allow any method of the `Math` object and also normal math using standard operators. Another problem with this is that JavaScript can be disabled and modified, which could be a security concern. It would therefore be great if I could do this scanning using **PHP**.
2. Execute the equation in a "safe environment". Now I don't know if this is possible in JavaScript, but I am basically looking for something where the function that is being executed can't access or modify any functions (except any methods of the `Math` object) and can't change any of the global variables, including the `document` variable. I don't know whether this is possible or not but maybe somebody knows something.

Thanks for your help, Moritz

UPDATE: I have found a way. I made a function which shadows all global variables and functions with a local variable. This is the function:

```
function safeEval(string,banned) {
    for(var i=0;i<banned.length;i++) {
        eval('var '+banned[i]);
    }
    return eval(string);
}
```

Where `banned` is an array of strings which will be shadowed. To block all global variables, you can call it like this:

```
safeEval('document.write("test")',Object.keys(window))
```

This will throw an error, which is exactly what I want. `Object.keys(window)` will return an array of all global variables (and functions), including `safeEval`.

ANOTHER UPDATE: As Rainer Plumer pointed out, this is not safe as you can use `this` as follows: `safeEval('this.document.write("test")',Object.keys(window))`

Hope I could help. Moritz

Comment: Do you expect to show a text of result on page after run eval()?

Comment: Your safe eval is not as safe as you think :) 
safeEval('this.document.write(this.document.cookie)',Object.keys(window))

Comment: @RainerPlumer thanks. Gonna go with the iframe then.

Comment: @Simon.Lay no, that's exactly what I don't want to happen, as I don't want the user to be able to enter any JavaScript code he wants. It throws an error, which is exactly what I intended. But as Rainer Plumer said this method is not safe, so I'm going to use your suggestion with an Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The "safe environment" is a good idea; It can achieve by `Iframe`.

According to your description, you need a "safe environment" to run a JavaScript equation, I think `Iframe` is very good to do that. This process runs a JavaScript equation can be done in `Iframe`, and it is safe because the page and `Iframe` are independency `document`.

Then you can use `postMessage` or something else to get result from Iframe, show it to users. You have to use another domain in Iframe that can ensure nobody can get users cookie or something else important, one of the famous website is [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) doing that.

Comment: Does this mean I have to own another domain or can I just use any domain or maybe a different subdomain? How about the solution I found (see my original post, I added an update)?

Comment: I found out that the sandbox attribute treats the iframe like it is from another origin. It wasn't able to read cookies after I added this. To allow script execution it has to be `sandbox="allow-scripts"`

Comment: @MoritzP. The solution you found(your updating)  is good but it is hard to check all javascript sentences and all subtle situations. It is like the sql injection, it is hard to defend it perfect.  Your solution is getting effect but not perfect.

Comment: @MoritzP. The sandbox does'n works when user visits your site use IE9 or another low version browser.

Comment: @MoritzP. All I want to say is that security is a huge topic, it is hard to do it best, but we should do our best, what a security level your website achieve is depends on your cost.

Comment: Using Iframe is works for you as you said "safe environment", global variable is not influenced,  two different environments, independence html document, etc.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will consider using a different domain for the Iframe. Problem is now: It is not completely safe. If you enter `while(true){}` or any other infinite loop into the editor, the whole website freezes. How can I solve this? I have already tried running the script in the Iframe asynchronously, but it doesn't seem like that worked. I don't want to allow any loops at all. I thought about setting a timeout and detecting if the script is still running after like 100 ms, but the parent script also freezes. What can I do to deal with that?

Comment: @MoritzP. Well, I think the infinite loop is not about security, it is about the user experience. It is like someone answer very rough on the Stackoverflow but it is not a security question, you can report the guy to the website admins, let them doing something.  I suggest you can build a report system, then users can report some unfriendly math formula.

Comment: sorry for the late reply - yes, but if an infinite loop is stored in the database and other users open it it will also affect their user experience. I am now just scanning the string for `for(` and `while(` (also with spaces in between) and I do not evaluate it if I find something.